# linux replacing line in text file

Tags: linux

I have a file in the following format:

```
[users]
admin = 123456
user1 = 987654
```

its a password file and i need to change the users password. I can get the information needed but I dont know how to replace it.
this is how i read the information:

```
admin=$(awk -F"[ \t]*=[ \t]*" '$1 == "admin" { print $2 }' file)
```

this returns me the password but i dont know how to replace it. I looked at using sed but im unsure on how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a basic sed question and if your usernames and passwords don't contain spaces

```
USER=admin ; sed  "s/$USER = .*$/$USER = newpw/" file
```

shows

```
[users]
admin = newpw
user1 = 987654
```

use with the `-i.bak` option to edit the file and create a backup with the `.bak` extension.

In any case, I hope you don't store the passwords in plain.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to be fancy with field separator

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=" = "}{ if($1=="admin") $2="abcdef" }'1 file
```

gives

```
[users]
admin = abcdef
user1 = 987654
```